# DIG DS KO on server but OK on local

Tags: python, python-3.x, dns, dnssec

I’m trying to retrieve the domain DS entry for DNSSEC.

I put this code in my file :

```py
n = dns.name.from_text(domain_name)
answers = dns.resolver.resolve(n, rdtype=dns.rdatatype.DS)
return [rdata.to_text() for rdata in answers]
```

In local it's work, but if i try on my VPS server i have this error :

> All nameservers failed to answer the query lunivers.fr. IN DS: Server Do53:127.0.0.53@53 answered NOTIMP

I tried with this code after that :

```py
res = dns.resolver.Resolver()

res.set_flags(dns.flags.CD|dns.flags.RD)
res.use_edns(0, dns.flags.EDNSFlag.DO)
a = res.resolve("com", "ds")
print(a.response)
```

But i have the same issue ..

Do you have an idea ? I don't find how to correct it..

It's the server who block to request ?

Thx !